# Highlightened the Categories of the current post, from the list of categories of the Custom Post Type

Tags: categories, custom-post-type, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, post-type

I have a code that displays a list of categories of Custom post types. And since it is displayed on the sidebar of the Single post template. I want to also change the text color of the categories that are assigned to the current post.
Is this possible?

I have the code

```
<?php
        $args = array(
                   'taxonomy' => 'services',
                   'orderby' => 'name',
                   'order'   => 'ASC'
               );

       $cats = get_categories($args);

       foreach($cats as $cat) {
    ?>
          <a href="<?php echo get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) ?>">
               <?php echo $cat->name; ?>
          </a><br>
        <?php
       }
     ?>
```

Change the text color of the categories that are assigned to the current post.